# disable links of previous element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, breadcrumbs

Now I have a sitemap such as this: Home > About Us > Who we Are. Can I use jQuery to disable the link for About Us leaving Home to be still active? Also if the site map increases to this level Home > Services > Consulting > Business > Training. Would it be achievable using jQuery to disable the Business, consulting and Services link, but still making the 'Home' link active.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. However, we'd need to know more about your HTML structure and the layout of your site to offer any help.

Comment: yes it is achievable using jQuery. But isnt it better if you do it on server side?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a little more information is needed to give you exactly what you want - for example are you trying to keep the first link active? Or the first link with "Home" in its text?

Regardless, something like this sounds like what you're after:

```
// Disable all links except first
$("#sitemap a:gt(0)").removeAttr("href")

// Disable all links except those containing the word 'Home'
$("#sitemap a:not(:contains('Home'))").removeAttr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/HTGBE/2/

```
<a href="http://jquery.com">Link</a> > 
<a href="http://jquery.com">Link</a> >
<a href="http://jquery.com">Link</a> >
<a href="http://jquery.com">Link</a> >
<a href="http://jquery.com">Link</a> >
<a href="http://jquery.com">Link</a> >
<a href="http://jquery.com">Link</a>
```

and the JS:

```
$('a:not(:first):not(:last)').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: +1 for preventing the link's default action, which is less "hacky" than removing the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing your actual HTML, but it should be easily doable.  Let's say your HTML looks like:

```
<div id="sitemap">
    <a href="/home">Home</a> &gt;
    <a href="/home/about">About Us</a> &gt;
    <a href="/home/about/who">Who We Are</a>
</div>
```

What you want to do is change all the anchors except the first to span's with the same content.  Run this every time the page loads in a document ready handler.  Note that you may need to add classes/css as necessary to maintain the correct styling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('#sitemap a:not(:first)').wrap('<span></span>').unwrap();
   });
</script>
```